# How to add a user profile page to frontend?

Tags: users, woocommerce-offtopic, front-end, profiles

I am looking in using wordpress for ecommerce by using woocommerce, as a newbie i don't know how to set up a user profile page outside wordpress installation (so the clients don't see the back end profile in wordpress).

Also, if some one know a complete shop theme in wordpress that has already this feature, that will make my life easier.

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using WooCommerce, they have a shortcode that displays the logged in user's account details on a front end page:

`[woocommerce_my_account]`